# Can only pull once from remote git repository

Tags: git

can somebody tell me why I can only pull one time from the remote in git. For the second time it fails and I am getting the message , Already up to date.

I am experimenting. Both the remote and the local repo have the file test.txt , but with different content. the first time I pull using

git pull heroku master

it worked, and i chose not to accept the incoming change and keep my local file the same. theoretically, I should be able to pull again, however the second time it fails with the message "Already up to date".

Is it because of the Fetch_Head that is pointing to the same content ?
I tried to reset Fetch_Head with reset --hard Fetch_Head, however I still cannot pull from the remote.

Comment: Why should you be able to pull again? You are already on the latest commit. If you want to go back a commit, you can do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` but be careful.

Comment: I am doing some experimentation. I purposely discard the incoming change from the latest pull from the remote repo. However I noticed that after that I cannot pull again. What if someone accidentally clicks on keep local changes , but he wanted to save the incoming changes

Answer (score 0):

Pull is fetch + merge: the fetch part is already completed.

Check your `git status`: if HEAD is at `master` *and* `heroku/master`, there is nothing more to pull.

If you want your content to reflect heroku/master, try the new [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) command (Git 2.23+):

```
git restore -s heroku/master -SW -- .
```

This assumes you don't have any work in progress, as it is akin to a `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I pull from the remote, and I accidently delete those files. How can I pull again ?

Comment: @masterinex Yes: the restore command will... restore them. No need to pull again: the history is stored in your local `remotes/heroku` namespace in your local repository.

Comment: I tried git restore -s origin/master -SW -- , but I am getting the message; you must specify path to restore.

Comment: @masterinex the final "`.`" is the path: `-- .` To be done at the root folder of your local repository.

Comment: Is this different from git clone "remote" ?

Comment: @masterinex yes: a `git clone` would contact the remote repository over the network. `git restore` only deals with your local repository in your `.git` subolder.